# TensorFlow SparseCategoricalAccuracy metric computation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to compute the accuracy using TensorFlow's 'SparseCategoricalAccuracy' [TensorFlow 2.0] and have a confusion as to the computed value and the value I calculate manually-

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

m.update_state(
    y_true = [[2], [1], [3]],
    y_pred = [[0.1, 0.9, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.02, 0.5, 0.8]],
    sample_weight = [1, 1, 1]
    # or-
    # sample_weight = None
    )

m.result().numpy()
# 0.33333334
```

Here, shouldn't the accuracy be 66.67% instead of 33.33% since the first and third predictions in 'y_pred' match y_true'?

Again,

```
m.reset_states()                                                       

y_pred = [[0.1, 0.4, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.2, 0.1, 0.7]]           
m.update_state(y_true=y_true, y_pred=y_pred, sample_weight=None)

m.result().numpy()                                                     
# 0.6666667


y_true                                                                 
# [[2], [1], [3]]

y_pred                                                                 
# [[0.1, 0.4, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.2, 0.1, 0.7]]
```

Here, the accuracy should be 33.33% since only one of the 'y_pred' viz., the third prediction matches that of 'y_true'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your labels need to be zero-indexed. Then you will get the correct accuracy.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

m.update_state(
    # We have changed y_true = [[2], [1], [3]] to the following
    y_true = [[1], [0], [2]],
    y_pred = [[0.1, 0.9, 0.8], [0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.02, 0.5, 0.8]],
    sample_weight = [1, 1, 1]
    # or-
    # sample_weight = None
    )

m.result().numpy()
```